# Connecting to SQL via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I´m trying to connect to SQL server via PowerShell. I tried using the code below,but I keep getting the same error. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

```
param
(   
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]  #servername
    [string]$SQLServer,

    # [Parameter(Mandatory)]  #database
    # [string]$SQLDBName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]  #user ID
    [string]$uid

)

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx"-AsPlainText -Force #heslo
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID= $uid; Password= $pwd" 
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = 'StoredProcName'
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection 
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd 
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet) 
$SqlConnection.Close()
```

The error looks like this:

> Exception calling "Fill" with "1" argument(s): "Login failed for user 'aims'."
>   At C:\Users\salema\Documents\SQL.ps1:24 char:1
>   + $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException

Comment: The error is pretty blatant.  Does the user "aims" have proper SQL permissions to login/perform the actions?

Comment: Yes, it´s testing account made for this puropose only.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `Open()` method to open the SQL connection. Try adding

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "xxx"-AsPlainText -Force #heslo
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; User ID= $uid; Password= $pwd" 

# Open the SQL connection
$SqlConnection.Open()
```